# How to use onClick and onLongPress in ListActivity?

Tags: android-activity, onclicklistener, listactivity, onlongclicklistener

I want to create a listview from which we can use onclick and in which on long press a Context menu comes out. the code is

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String quizlist[]={"Normal","MCQ 2 Options","MCQ 3 options","MCQ 4 Options"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> ab=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,quizlist);
        setListAdapter(ab);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register an `AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener` on the `ListView`. So what you need to do is find the list view:

in `onCreate` try

```
((ListView) getView).setOnItemLongKlickListener(...)
```

or

```
((ListView) findViewById(<the id of your list view>).setOnItemLongKlickListener(...)
```

When implementing an `OnItemLongClickListener` you will have to override the `onItemLongClick` method:

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html#onItemLongClick(android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long)):

```
public abstract boolean onItemLongClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

> Added in API level 1 Callback method to be invoked when an item in
>   this view has been clicked and held. Implementers can call
>   getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to access the data associated
>   with the selected item.

```
Parameters 
parent      The AbsListView where the click happened 
view        The view within the AbsListView that was clicked 
position    The position of the view in the list 
id          The row id of the item that was clicked

Returns true if the callback consumed the long click, false otherwise
```

So, `parent` is your `ListView`. `view` is the view of the *long clicked' list item. `position` is the position inside the list and thus also the position in your array. For `id` I am not sure whether the default implementations returns a constant or the `position`.

Comment: Can you please explain what does each argument over here represent?      AdapterView.OnItemClickListener ss=new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
     long arg3) {
    
   }
  };

Comment: 1) `OnItemClickListener` is the wrong one. You wanted an *OnItem**Long**ClickListener*; 2) I'll add something to my answer.

Comment: The arguments are the same for both listeners